# What's the command to open a file and jump to an specific line in vi?

Tags: vi

It was something like

```
vi -line:123 myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vi +123 myfile.txt
```

Comment: Found it here btw: http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~kgao/Linux_in_a_Nutshell_3rd_Edition/CH11_02.HTM